# Precompilation for Deployment

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-compiler

After exploring Precompilation for Deployment topic I want to enhance my build process. Now, what I do is:

- prepare web site using Web One Click Publish, for instance to `c:\www\app` directory, and that directory is available in IIS via app (`localhost/app`)
- I launch `aspnet_compiler.exe -v app c:\www\appprecompiled -f`

Now I have ready precompiled application in `c:\www\appprecompiled` and everything is fine. However my application is quite big, and Publishing it (step 1) take about 5 minutes from scratch. So I wonder if it is possible to avoid step one , and perform step 2 (precompilation) with source folder pointing to solution folder. I tried something like this:

```
aspnet_compiler.exe -v codeapp c:\code\app -f
```

Where `c:\code\app` is the folder with web.config etc files, basically it's a project with web site and that folder is avaliable via `http://localhost/codeapp`.

But when launching that command, I get errors about missing global.asax or web.config errors:

> C:\code\app\obj\debug\package\packagetmp\web.config(18):
>   error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use
>   a section registered as 
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'
>   beyond application level.   This error
>   can be caused by a virtual directory
>   not being configured  as an
>   application in IIS.

And for the record, I use Application, not Virtual Directory.

So is there a way to perform precompilation on a plain web site folder?

Comment: Hi, yes it runs. For instance when I run Build from visual studio and then access http://localhost/codeapp it works. Is that what you asked for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used

> aspnet_compiler -p
>   physicalOrRelativePath -v / targetPath

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976(v=VS.80).aspx and removed obj folder prior to executing it, and precompilation works :)